# What is this CSS syntax saying: 'selector.stuff1.stuff2'?

Tags: html, css, syntax, css-selectors

I was looking at the CSS for a [CSS Menu Maker design](http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/elegant-accordion-menu#), and it uses a syntax I haven't seen before.

```css
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
  background: url(images/icon_minus.png) 98% center no-repeat;
}
```

The `li.has-sub.active` part - is that saying 'a li that has the classes  has-sub and active'?

I also haven't seen an instance before of combining the syntax for 'child of' with the syntax for 'has this class'. Is that good practice?

Comment: It isn't necessarily bad practice, although it seems like a lot of unnecessary nesting. It would be much better to add a class on the target `span` instead of this long selector, both for maintainability and for ease of overriding in the future.

Comment: @JoshRutherford Sorry Deleted. I was just amazed.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar

Comment: My philosophy: Always referring to [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax), `4. Selector syntax` states: `A selector is a chain of one or more sequences of simple selectors separated by combinators.` where `A sequence of simple selectors is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator`. Also have a look at: [combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) and [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Comment: @Antiga I wondered if it could really be the case that nesting of that kind would be the best way of handling a high degree of specificity, like Josh seems to be referring to. I don't write html / css a lot (obviously), so I'd like to avoid using a syntax if it might cause confusion for me later.

Comment: I am thoroughly confused by the close votes. Where in the question does the OP ask for off-site references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a selector that includes several `.` (class) indicators, then that means the element must have all listed classes

> `li.has-sub.active` is saying that it selects `<li>` elements which also must have the class "has-sub" *and* "active".

As for "Is this good practice?", in my opinion it is. All it does is allow for the ability to be more restrictive with the style selection. This can save time and also is a good way to provide a hook for other types of dom selection in JavaScript.

**MDN**

*CSS Selectors*
For more information on CSS Selectors, the Mozilla Developer Network has very good information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors .

*CSS Specificity*
In addition, different selectors have different weights. This can cause certain selectors to take precedence, and properly planning for that means taking "Specificity" into account which is also at play here in your example. The MDN has a good article on that subject as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity .

Answer (score 2):

Two selectors together with no space inbetween them are selecting the same element. It is a normal use of CSS, not bad practice at all.
According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors):

> You can also combine selectors, making a more specific selector.
>
> For example, the selector `.key` selects all elements that have the class name key. The selector `p.key` selects only `<p>` elements that have the class name key.
>
> You are not restricted to the two special attributes, class and id. You can specify other attributes by using square brackets. For example, the selector `[type='button']` selects all elements that have a type attribute with the value button.

For example:

```
div.classname{}
```

Will select `<div class="classname"></div>`

```
span#elementid.classname
```

Will select `<span id="elementid" class="classname"></span>`

```
.classname.classtwo
```

Will select `<span class="classname classtwo"></span>`

In your CSS, the selectors:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span
```

Would select a HTML structure like:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub active"><a><span>I am selected</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[And here is a nice little demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ntzp4yhL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way, as you may need to add multiple classes for a single element and have different styles inherited. You can think of Multiple Inheritance as a crazy comparison.

```css
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
}
```

Then it selects:

```css
#cssmenu                 - ID
  ul                     - directly inside the above element (because of >).
    li                   - directly inside the above element (because of >).
      .has-sub.active    - LI with both the classes.
```

This is absolutely the right way to write CSS. Because, this will be something aligned with Modular CSS and you can mix and match different CSS component styles.